# How do you make 29 only using the numbers 1 2 3 4

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

How do you make 29 with only using the numbers 1 2 3 4?
I have tried a lot of solutions and please remember that you can't use the number 5

Comment: What operations are allowed to be used? How many times can each digit $1,2,3,4$ be used? Must they all be used? Is concatenation (e.g. $21,13$) allowed? I'm voting to close as "too broad" until more detail of the rules is provided.

Comment: It says numbers, not digits.  Each number once goes without saying.  But the list of valid operations is clearly missing.

Answer (score 2):

Here's several ways:

> $31-\frac42$
>  $4!+3!-2+1$
>  $3^{2+1}+\sqrt{4}$
>  $2^{4+1}-3$
>  $42-13$

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways could be :-

> $2^2+3^2+4^{3-1}$

Comment: It is likely that each number should appear only once, otherwise there are a lot of very obvious answers.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier That’s more a fault of the question than of the answer, though.